# Python 2.7.5 how to accumulate and declare values in an array/ list from user input?

Tags: python, arrays, list

My apologizes for the basic question, I'm working through a programming book discussing arrays, Using python 2.7.5 I want to ask the user for input and store the numbers in an array, I can assign a value in the array to a string but don't want to do that, instead of doing:

```
emp_name[0] = raw_input("please enter employee name")
```

I want to add values to the array emp_name, and recall something like: emp_name[1] and have the 2nd name entered displayed for the user. I apologize for the novice question but I'm still wrapping my head around arrays.
I think I have to use a for numbers in range loop, or a while loop? Please assist

Comment: If you are a new python programmer then consider using Python 3.X rather than Python 2.X since it is already rapidly migrating that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a shot

```
emp_names = []
num_to_enter = 10
while num_to_enter > 0:
    emp_names.append(raw_input("enter name"))
    num_to_enter -= 1

print emp_names[0]

#do what you need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are looking for is dictionary, not array. Although, you can make array in that way which can be highly inefficient for searching, particularly when it involves large amount of data. If you want to stick with array, consider tuple rather than array.

Storing in dictionary can be done as key/value pair like you want.

```
my_store=dict()
or 
my_store={}
```

and after that, you can store the data like you wanted as:

```
my_store[0]="emp_name_1"
```

My answer is based on the fact that you want to identify your data using some key, not just index like 1. If index is all you want to refer to your data, array is not a problem. But I think I hastened to answer you without looking and asking you properly if you just are looking to use index or other strings to fetch the stored data.

If array is all your are looking you can do as simple as:

```
emp_names = []
while True:
    inp=raw_input("enter_name or nothing but enter to exit")
    if inp='':
       break
    else:
         emp_names.append(inp)
```

And you can use index 0 referring to the first element and so on to fetch the data.